# How to convert curl to php i try not work

Tags: php, curl

this image capture from firebug . it post image binary data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbQIV.png)

```
curl 'http://xxxxx.com/xxxx/cccc' 
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;            
boundary=---------------------------1145250413327763230421052055' --data-binary 
$'-----------------------------1145250413327763230421052055\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
name="user_image"; filename="dscn6949_938.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r
\n\r\n-----------------------------1145250413327763230421052055--\r\n'
```

i try this code into below but not work

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
"Content-Type: multipart/form-data;   
boundary=---------------------------1145250413327763230421052055"
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://xxxxx.com/xxxx/cccc");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$datapost = array(
            "user_image" => "@111.jpg".";filename=111.jpg;type=image/jpeg"
            );

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datapost);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Your commandline curl displays `user_profile_image` but you have used `user_image`.

Comment: You should be able to leave all of those headers out. Also remove anything but the `@` and filename from the value of "user_image". Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: sorry i use user_image but still not work